# Name that blog entry - Modelling changes over time with two db columns only

Tags: design-patterns, time, blogs, audit

I vaguely remember reading a blog entry (written by a well-known blogger I think) about how to model price changes over time, and that you could model most changes by saving two dates only (two columns in a db). The blog talked about prices on a website changing over time and how you could figure out the right price to charge knowing only when the purchase had been made.

Very vague, I know, but my google-fu is failing me, everyone at IRC are busy talking about other stuff and I don't know what to do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that i meant [Patterns for things that change with time](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/timeNarrative.html) by Martin Fowler, but more generally about [Bitemporal data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitemporal_data).

Comment: The Martin Fowler piece is a neat summary of all the issues.  I could have done with this last summer, to settle a long-running argument, er, design discussion.